# How to programmatically open the option modal and listen to changes?

Tags: api

I would like to open such a modal programmatically and then listen to events related to this modal (such as "option created", "option updated", "modal closed" etc). I tried to look at the CiviCRM source code but could not find API for that. Is there such a possibility?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be possible:

```
CRM.loadForm('/some/url')
  .on('crmFormSuccess', function (event, data) {
    // do smth
});
```

Ref: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve exactly? Your solution works for the UI but will never catch any of the changes done via the API?

So if you want to just catch the UI actions, your solution will be fine. But if you want to catch all changes to an option group you might miss a few.

Comment: Yes, I need to listen to changes via UI only.